# logic for parsing html using simple html dom

Tags: simple-html-dom

I have hard time parsing a structure using `simple html dom`

```
`<div class="class1">class</div>
`<div class="class2">data2</div>
`<div class="class2">data3</div>

`<div class="class1">text</div>
`<div class="class2">...</div>
```

Since structure is not nested so I have hard time parsing it.
I want database be grabbed as `class1` as main heading and `class2` as sub. So for every `class1`, I want to read all `class2` tags until another `class1` arrives. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can check class elements to see if you reached another `class1` element. Something like this explains the general idea:

```
$str =<<<'html'

<div class="class1">class</div>
<div class="class2">data2</div>
<div class="class2">data3</div>

<div class="class1">text</div>
<div class="class2">...</div>
html;

$html = str_get_html($str);
// Store all results in a multi dimensional array
$result = [];

$group = -1;
foreach ($html->find('div') as $elem) {
    // if element class is class1, create a new array to gather data
    if($elem->class == 'class1') {
        $group++;
        $result[$group] = [];
    }
    $result[$group][] = $elem->plaintext;
}

print_r($result);
```

So everytime we encounter a new element with `class1` we start to gather information in a new array, so the final result is a nested array that groups elements the way you described.